# Number of digits within an interval

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

I need to calculate how many times each digit appears within the numeric sequence from 1 to ***given number***.

**Example:**

Input: 12

Output: 5 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

*Explanation:*

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1 0  1 1  1 2

The first number is the quantity of ones, the second one – of twos...the last one of zeros

So far, I have written a function that splits any integer into parts (2512 will be 2000 500 10 2). Maybe it can be useful for future executions:

```
                function splitToParts(x) {
                var multiplier = 1;

                while (x > 0) {
                    var result = x % 10;

                    if (result > 0) {
                        parts.unshift(result * multiplier);
                    }

                    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
                    multiplier *= 10;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it would be much easier for people to help you if you could provide some code of what you have so far, and explain more about what it is you need help on

Comment: @NewToJS , honestly, I do not have any complete idea wherefrom should I start solving this problem, because there is so much stuff to be calculated and considered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2000, 500 and 10 are just not digits, so for direct counting they are not feasible to work with. A simple approach would be saying that you are always interested in the least significant digit (the "ones"), and "consume" the number as long as it is not 0.

For a single number it would be this simple:

```js
function digits(number){
    var retval=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    while(number>0){
        retval[number%10]++;
        number=Math.floor(number/10);
    }
    return retval;
}
console.log(digits(123).join()); // join just makes it a single line, looks better
```

Then one may make the statistics updateable via accepting an argument for it. It does not even have to be mandatory, the function can simply create it if it is missing:

```js
function digits(number,stats){
    var retval=stats || [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    while(number>0){
        retval[number%10]++;
        number=Math.floor(number/10);
    }
    return retval;
}

var stats=digits(123);
console.log(stats.join());
console.log(digits(234,stats).join());
```

And make it a loop:

```js
function digits(number,stats){
    var retval=stats || [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    while(number>0){
        retval[number%10]++;
        number=Math.floor(number/10);
    }
    return retval;
}

function intervalDigits(min,max){
    var stats;
    for(var i=min;i<=max;i++)
        stats=digits(i,stats);
    return stats;
}

console.log(intervalDigits(1,12).join());
```

That would be a "brute force", but working solution in JavaScript.

Then one can go for maths instead of brute forcing, and start working with the 2000-500-10-2 "decomposition", finding patterns in "contribution" to the statistics for digits at 'ones', 'tens', 'hundreds', and so on. These contributions will not be trivial, so the existing snippets may come useful to check what happens around different "transitions".

```js
function digits(number,stats){
    var retval=stats || [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    while(number>0){
        retval[number%10]++;
        number=Math.floor(number/10);
    }
    return retval;
}

function intervalDigits(min,max){
    var stats;
    for(var i=min;i<=max;i++)
        stats=digits(i,stats);
    return stats;
}

for(var i=1;i<21;i++)console.log("1-"+i,intervalDigits(1,i).join());
console.log("---");
for(var i=95;i<115;i++)console.log("1-"+i,intervalDigits(1,i).join());
console.log("---");
var x100=intervalDigits(1,100);
var x200=intervalDigits(1,200);
var x300=intervalDigits(1,300);
console.log("1-100",x100.join());
console.log("1-200",x200.join());
console.log("1-300",x300.join());
console.log("---");
console.log("1-100 -> 1-200",x200.map((x,i)=>x-x100[i]).join());
console.log("1-200 -> 1-300",x300.map((x,i)=>x-x200[i]).join());
console.log("1-100 -> 1-300",x300.map((x,i)=>x-x100[i]).join());
```

Given the range of 10<sup>18</sup>, you are most likely expected to pursue this track (too), but here and now this 'starter pack' is what I have had time for.

Comment: can you please explain more specifically how does "stats" work?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you ask about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators - so when ```stats``` is provided, it is assigned to ```retval```. However when it is not there, it becomes ```undefined``` which is considered ```false``` in a logical expression, thus ```||``` continues with evaluating the right side and 'starts' a new array with 0-s.